# Laravel inertia react - pass a prop

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, inertiajs, laravel-breeze

I installed the breeze + react starter kit. Also, got the Spatie permissions, and seeded some roles, users etc.

I made a middleware to redirect the user based on role, and also a dashboard page specific to a certain role. All works fine, except I don't seem to be able to pass variables to the react view - dev tools show me an 'undefined' error basically.

app/Http/Middleware/CheckUserRole.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class CheckUserRole
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        if ($user->hasRole('BankAdmin')) {
            return redirect('/admin/dashboard');
        }
        if ($user->hasRole('BankUser')) {
            return redirect('/user/dashboard');
        }
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

in my routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return Inertia::render('Welcome', [
        'canLogin' => Route::has('login'),
        'canRegister' => Route::has('register'),
        'laravelVersion' => Application::VERSION,
        'phpVersion' => PHP_VERSION,
    ]);
});

Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return Inertia::render('Dashboard',
    );
})->middleware(['auth', 'verified', 'checkrole'])->name('dashboard');

Route::get('/user/dashboard', UserDashboardController::class);

require __DIR__ . '/auth.php';
```

app/Http/Controllers/UserDashboardController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Inertia\Inertia;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserDashboardController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Return all users.
     *
     * @return \Inertia\Response
     */
    public function __invoke()
    {
        return Inertia::render('UserDashboard', [
            'message' => 'You are logged in as BankUser',
        ]);
    }
}
```

resources/js/Pages/UserDashboard.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import Authenticated from '@/Layouts/Authenticated';
import {Head} from '@inertiajs/inertia-react';

export default function UserDashboard(props) {
    return (
        <Authenticated
            auth={props.auth}
            errors={props.errors}
            message={props.message}
            header={<h2 className="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">Dashboard</h2>}
        >
            <Head title="User Dashboard"/>

            <div className="py-12">
                <div className="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                    <div className="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-sm sm:rounded-lg">
                        <div className="p-6 bg-white border-b border-gray-200">You're logged in - BankUser!{message} </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Authenticated>
    );
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Why is message undefined?

Comment: Oh, and when I console.log(props) - I see my message there. Just don't get why I can't access it in the page?

Answer (score 1):

Solved. it's `{props.message}` - or can extract props like:

```
export default function UserDashboard({auth, errors, message}) {
```